# Installing Angular2 Material Breaks app

Tags: angular, angular-material

problem

- i try to run

  > npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
- its then break app

Error

> Failed to compile.
>   ./~/@angular/cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js
>           Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
>          'D:\app\node_modules\@angular\cdk\@angular\cdk.es5.js'
>           @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 49:0-46
>           @ ./src/main.ts
>           @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

app.module.ts

```
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';

//cannot found module @angular/cdk
```

package.json

```
    {
    "name": "angular2-bug-testing",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.3.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.11",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
    }
    }
```

- can anyone suggest angular material is unstable.
- its creating lots of problem with angular2 app.

Comment: You need at least angular 4.4.1

Comment: you say i need i need to upgrade angular

Comment: Might be, I don;t know what version you are using.

Comment: i m using 4.3.2 angular version

Comment: You need to update your dependencies. Update your Angular/cli to 1.4.2 and run `npm update`

Comment: i tried npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean the install again now i get bulk of issue

Comment: Just increase the version i your package.json and run `npm update`

Comment: There's no support for Angular 4.4 at the moment...

Comment: or i should degarde angular version pleasesuggest.